# How to connect a toolbar button to a script to perform some python action

Tags: qgis

I have created a toolbar and a button for the toolbar in pyqgis using the following script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
toolbar = iface.addToolBar(u'My toolbar')
iface.toolButton = QToolButton()
iface.toolButton.setIcon(QIcon("myIcon.png"))
toolbar.addWidget(iface.toolButton)
```

In addition, I have a simple python script that perform a simple action, for example:

```
def my_action()
    perform_action
```

How do I connect the "def my_action()" script to the button above. So that it calls the my_action function when the user click the button?

Comment: I've found the answer: iface.toolButton.clicked.connect(toolAction)

Comment: How does this "toolAction" refer to your script? Can you give a precise example ?